# Can I join smoothly (and convexly) two pieces of function?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convex-analysis, convolution, interpolation

Let $$f(x)=(x^2-1)^2\,,\quad g(x)=x^2$$ for $x>0$. Their plots cross at two points, the largest is $x_0=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$.

[[image: Plot. In green: <span class=]$g(x)$, in purple: $f(x)$, black dot: $x_0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHzkY.png)

I would like to build a smooth function $F\in C^\infty(0,\infty)$ such that
$$ F(x) \,=\,\begin{cases} \,f(x) &\textrm{for } x\geq x_0+\delta\\[4pt]
\,g(x) &\textrm{for }0<x\leq x_0-\delta \end{cases} $$
for some small $\delta>0\,$.
In other terms I have to interpolate on the interval $[x_0-\delta,\,x_0+\delta]$ respecting infinitely many conditions at the endpoints:
$$ F^{(k)}(x_0+\delta)=f^{(k)}(x_0+\delta) \;,\quad F^{(k)}(x_0-\delta)=g^{(k)}(x_0-\delta) $$
for all $k\in\mathbb N\,$.
**Questions:**

1. Does $F$ exist?
2. Is it possible to write it explicitely?
3. Does asking only $F\in C^2(0,\infty)$ make things easier?
4. Can I require that $F$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ ?

**Edit.**
In a previous answer, that has been deleted, it was suggested to take
$$ F(x) \,:=\, (1-h(x))\,g(x)\,+\, h(x)\,f(x) $$
setting $h(x):=0$ for $x<x_0-\delta$, $h(x):=1$ for $x>x_0+\delta$, and
$$ h(x) \,:=\,
\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{x-(x_0-\delta)}\;\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{(x_0+\delta)-x}\bigg)\bigg)$$
for $x_0-\delta\leq x\leq x_0+\delta\,$.
This choice of $F$ is $C^\infty(0,\infty)$, but it is not convex.

**Edit2.**
As suggested in the comments, I tried to compute $5^{th}$ degree polynomial interpolation, namely
$$ F(x)= c_0+c_1 x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4+c_5x^5\,, \quad x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$$
where the six coefficients are chosen to verify six conditions:
$$ F^{(k)}(x_0-\delta)=g^{(k)}(x_0-\delta) \,,\quad F^{(k)}(x_0+\delta)=f^{(k)}(x_0+\delta)\,,\quad k=0,1,2 \;.$$
For $\delta=\frac{1}{10}$, the resulting function turns out to be $C^2$ and convex on $(0,\infty)$, with $F''\geq g''$.
Is there a way to prove this without computing the interpolating polynomial?

Comment: You certainly cannot interpolate two convex functions by a convex function in general: namely, you would have $F(x)\ge g'(x_0-\delta)(x-x_0+\delta)+g(x_0-\delta)$ for all $x\ge x_0-\delta$, and this may not be compatible with $F(x_0+\delta)=f(x_0+\delta)$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I think in my case this is fine for $\delta$ small, since $g'(x_0-\delta)<f'(x_0+\delta)$

Comment: For $C^2$ you can do it with a polynomial of degree $5$ (I think) since your values and derivatives specify $6$ conditions.

Comment: @EthanBolker and the resulting function would be $C^2$ and convex?

Comment: @tituf It will be twice differentiable if you match the second derivative. For $C^2$ (continuous second derivative) match the third derivative as well. I suspect it will be convex - calculate it to be sure.

Comment: @EthanBolker it seems long computations to do, is there no shortcut to prove that the result is convex? It would also be interesting to have a general theory for other functions $f,g$

Comment: @EthanBolker I did the computations with Wolfram and the result of degree $5$ polynomial interpolation seems to be convex. How did you guess it? Is it possible to know it a priori?

Comment: I guessed that it would be convex by looking at the picture and thinking about what the general fifth degree polynomial might look like. Not much room or opportunity for an inflection point in your interval. Once you have the formula you can prove convexity by calculating the second derivative. For a general theory all that matters is the local behavior near the two endpoints. Make a guess from the picture.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you. I'm sure your intuition comes from experience. The smooth interpolation sketched in the Edit1 does have an inflection point. If you plot them, the $C^2$ polynomial interpolation looks much more regular than the smooth one...

Comment: The slopes do not match, even if the curvatures might. A single polynomial cannot be found with full continuous differentiability.